# agGrid searching data using angular2 and typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, ag-grid

How can I set filtering in my agGrid component.
I saw a example from agGrid but it is written in javascript. 
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-filtering/index.php

But it seems I can't make this one work using my ts code below.

agGrid.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main';

import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/partials/agGrid/agGrid.html',
    directives: [AgGridNg2]
})
export class AgGridComponent {

    columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "Contact Name", field: "make" },
        { headerName: "Company Name", field: "model" },
        {
            headerName: "Last Event",
            field: "price",
            cellClass: 'rightJustify',
            cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
                return '$' + params.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); //thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/28324/elias-zamaria
            }
        },
        { headerName: "Contact Email", field: "model" },
        { headerName: "Work Phone", field: "model" }
    ];
    // put data directly onto the controller
    rowData = [
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
        { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
        { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 }
    ];

    gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
        rowData: null,
        enableFilter: true
    };



    values='';
    onKey(event:any) {
        this.values = event.target.value;
        this.gridOptions.columnDefs.setQuickFilter(this.values);
    }

    searchValue='';

}
```

grid.html

```html
<input placeholder="Filter..." type="text"
    [value]="searchValue"
    (input)="searchValue = $event.target.value"
/>

<ag-grid-ng2
  class="ag-fresh"
  enable-sorting
  enable-filter
  style="height: 300px" 
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
  (cellClicked)="onCellClicked()" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [rowData] = "rowData"> 
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Answer (score 6):

Bind the ngModel variable to "quickFilterText" attribute. "quickFilterText" is supposed to change to "quickFilter" in the future.

```
<input type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="searchValue" placeholder="quick filter..." /> 
<ag-grid-angular  
    class="data-grid ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData | async" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [quickFilterText]="searchValue"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: This way is neat and clean since no additional code is required. Simply add `quickFilterText` or `quickFilter` (it depends on the ag-grid version) to the ag-grid HTML element and bind it to your searchValue property. That's it. No keyup, oninput, change or any other events are needed to be listened.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you already solved this but for those who are currently looking, you can 2-way bind your input box to a variable in your code.

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onQuickFilterChanged()" 
    [(ngModel)]="quickSearchValue" placeholder="quick filter..." />
```

and your TS code like this:

```
quickSearchValue: string = '';

private onQuickFilterChanged() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(this.quickSearchValue);
}
```

Hope this helps.